# Extract LDA (linear discriminant analysis) data in R

Tags: r, analysis

When I run this line

```
my.lda<-lda(Group ~ X1+X2+X3+X4, data = df)
```

I get a long output that finish with this lines

```
Proportion of trace:

   LD1    LD2    LD3    LD4 

0.8750 0.0958 0.0286 0.0006
```

How can I store the LD1 and LD2 proportion of trace in separate variables?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
prop.table(my.lda$svd^2)
```

According to the documentation, `lda(...)$svd` is a vector of

> the singular values, which give the ratio of the between- and
>   within-group standard deviations on the linear discriminant variables.
>   Their squares are the canonical F-statistics.